# Is it possible to ascend (or descend) an escalator, without consuming any more power produced by the motor of the escalator?

Tags: energy, work

Is it possible to ascend (or descend) an escalator (which ascends with a constant speed), without consuming any more power (energy) produced by the motor of the escalator ?

I mean, find a way to walk on the escalator in which motor of the escalator doesn't need any more power than the situation in which no one is on it...

Actually, I , myself, think it is impossible! But if so, please help me to make a good justification!

Comment: Are you asking about walking up a down escalator, or down an up escalator, so that your height remains constant?

Comment: not exactly, but, that can be a question too! i think in that case the work of escalator is not zero, is it?

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can.

You have to "walk" in such a way that you will exert a force that is perpendicular to the motion of the escalator. 
Of course that means you will accelerate toward the bottom of the elevator, at the same rate as if you were on a frictionless slope.

You can still accend the elevator if your initial speed is high enough. (Please don't try anything like that in real life.)